# How can i reduce the following Laravel code?

Tags: php, laravel, design-patterns, coding-style

My application is working perfectly, but I'm trying to keep my code as simple and clean as possible.

I have a Controller that is receiving most of the data automatically, but I have 3 inputs that gonna be added to the request, more specifically,

- if the course is active(optional)
- is highlighted(optional),
- and the user id.

The first and second are being treated with `isset()`, and the third is defined by the authenticated user.

I would like to know if there is a better way to improve my code and simplify and remove useless lines of code.
I have been reading about `merge()` in the Laravel requests section of the documentation, but I couldn't apply it for some reason. My requests are located in the $data variable, and the course is created at the final by passing this variable to the model Course with method create.

The question is: is it possible to remove the $data declaration for the other cases and keep it only for `$data['is_active']`, `$data['is_highlighted']` and `$data['user_id']`, without missing the other parameters?

```php
    public function store(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, []);
        
        try{
            $data["user_id"] = Auth::user()->id;
            $data["name"] = $request->name;
            $data["objectives"] = $request->objectives;
            $data["requirements"] = $request->requirements;
            $data["description"] = $request->description;
            $data["content"] = $request->content;
            $data["duration"] = $request->duration;
            $data["video_link"] = $request->video_link;
            $data["is_active"] = isset($request->is_active) ? 1 : 0;
            $data["is_highlighted"] = isset($request->is_is_highlighted) ? 1 : 0;

            $imageName = time().'.'.$request->image->extension();

            $request->image->move(public_path('uploads/images/courses/'), $imageName);

            $image = Image::create([
                'path' => ('uploads/images/courses/'.$imageName),
                'alt_text' => $request->alt ? $request->alt : $request->title,
            ]);

            $data["image_id"] = $image->id;

            if(isset($request->is_published))
                $data["published_at"] = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
            
            $course = Course::create($data);
           

            return redirect()->route('courses.index')->withMessage(trans('crud.record_created'));
```

Comment: Cleaning up code might be better over at https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: A tip going forwards, the `Request` instance has a `only` method that returns an key, value array of the request. I've [mocked the request as an example](https://3v4l.org/DXflD) so you can get some understanding of it but it is [stated in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests#retrieving-a-portion-of-the-input-data). If you then want to add other things into the returned array, you can use `array_merge` or the shorthand `+`.

Comment: That's it! I trying to figure out how to apply array_merge in this case.

Comment: Because you're also using Eloquent, you have already specified the `$fillable` properties associated to that table. You could use reflection to get only the data from the request that model needs: `request()->only((new \ReflectionClass(Course::class))->getDefaultProperties()['fillable']);`. See [an example on 3v4l](https://3v4l.org/FuCZg)

Comment: This is not a good, searchable question title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce the number of lines like this

public function store(Request $request){
$this->validate($request, []);

```
    try {
        $data = $request->all();
        $data["user_id"] = Auth::user()->id;

        $imageName = time() . '.' . $request->image->extension();
        $request->image->move(public_path('uploads/images/courses/'), $imageName);
        $image = Image::create([
            'path' => ('uploads/images/courses/' . $imageName),
            'alt_text' => $request->alt ? $request->alt : $request->title,
        ]);

        $data["image_id"] = $image->id;
        $data["published_at"] = isset($request->is_published) ? Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString() : null;

        $course = Course::create($data);


        return redirect()->route('courses.index')->withMessage(trans('crud.record_created'));
    }
```

Comment: The problem with this is that gives the following error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation. I imagine that is because the 3 other inputs must be declared, but at the same time I have to figure out how to merge them with the other inputs. This happens by declaring the whole data, but I want to improve this and remove useless lines of code. That's the problem.

Comment: I think I have missed two fields 
        $data["is_active"] = isset($request->is_active) ? 1 : 0;
        $data["is_highlighted"] = isset($request->is_is_highlighted) ? 1 : 0;
because of this the error might be coming

Comment: Gives the same error, even with the additional code.

Comment: I think you should use Request validation and then `$data = $request->validated()` instead of `$request->all()`. In addition you will get a better security in input management.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found out how to solve the problem:

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, []);
    
    try{
        $request->merge(["user_id" => Auth::user()->id]);
        $request->merge(["is_active" => isset($request->is_active) ? 1 : 0]);
        $request->merge(["is_highlighted" => isset($request->is_highlighted) ? 1 : 0]);

        $imageName = time().'.'.$request->image->extension();

        $request->image->move(public_path('uploads/images/courses/'), $imageName);

        $image = Image::create([
            'path' => ('uploads/images/courses/'.$imageName),
            'alt_text' => $request->alt ? $request->alt : $request->title,
        ]);

        $request["image_id"] = $image->id;

        $this->courses->create($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('courses.index')->withMessage(trans('crud.record_created'));

    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($ex->getMessage())->withInput();
    }
}
```

By using this, your code gets more objective and clear, which allows other people understand better what you're doing.